# kineticjs shape in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, kineticjs

I'm trying to create a shape based on the following kineticjs JavaScript code:

```
var triangle = new Kinetic.Shape({
    drawFunc: function(canvas) {
      var context = canvas.getContext();
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(200, 50);
      context.lineTo(420, 80);
      context.quadraticCurveTo(300, 100, 260, 170);
      context.closePath();
      canvas.fillStroke(this);
    },
    fill: '#00D2FF',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4
  });
```

This is a sample that can be found on: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-shape-tutorial/

My typescript looks like this:

```
var square = new Kinetic.Shape({
        drawFunc: (canvas: any) => {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(25, 25);
            ctx.lineTo(475, 25);
            ctx.lineTo(475, 475);
            ctx.lineTo(25, 475);
            ctx.closePath();
            canvas.fillStroke(this);
        },
        fill: '#FF0000',
    });
```

The generated JavaScript looks like this:

```
var square = new Kinetic.Shape({
        drawFunc: function (canvas) {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(25, 25);
            ctx.lineTo(475, 25);
            ctx.lineTo(475, 475);
            ctx.lineTo(25, 475);
            ctx.closePath();
            canvas.fillStroke(_this);
        },
        fill: '#FF0000'
    });
```

The problem occurs on the `canvas.fillStroke(_this)` line. The `_this` is referencing my typescript class and not the generated shape like in the JavaScript sample. I also tried to replace the `canvas.fillStroke(this)` in my typescript with `() => canvas.fillStroke(this)`, but the result is the same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to avoid the fat arrow notation, which deliberately preserves the current context of `this` as `_this`.

So `drawFunc: (canvas: any) => {` should be `drawFunc: function(canvas:any){` etc.

See the difference here: http://bit.ly/10cpdWw

The comments here are useful regarding `_this` and `this`: http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/248

Comment: I modified my code like you suggest and it works, but I think I'm combining TypeScript with JavaScript in my TypeScript file, so this is not possible in a pure TypeScript manner?

Comment: TypeScript *is* JavaScript - just extended. The fat arrow notation performs a specific task. The full `function(canvas:any){` is just as valid TS.